# Using Groovy to replaceall from backslash to forward

Tags: groovy

I am having an issue with Groovy replace all. can someone suggest? I wanted to replace `\` with `/`.

```
String path= 'C:\path\of\my\file' // <- This path comes in dynamic, so I cannot have \\
path = path.replaceAll('\', '/')
println(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// If the value is coming in dynamically the `\\` won't
// be in the value, but if you want to represent a \ in source code
// like this it needs to be escaped. 
String path= 'C:\\path\\of\\my\\file'

path = path.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')
println(path)
```

**EDIT:**

I have created a runnable example that demonstrates pulling the values in dynamically.

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/asmescaping](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asmescaping).

[lib/src/main/resources/info.txt](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asmescaping/blob/71f3174f6c9f4dbcc1639f2a8f52ab7ef3c7f49c/lib/src/main/resources/info.txt)

```
C:\path\of\my\file
C:\path2\of\my\file
C:\path3\of\my\file
```

[lib/src/main/groovy/asmescaping/SomeClass.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asmescaping/blob/71f3174f6c9f4dbcc1639f2a8f52ab7ef3c7f49c/lib/src/main/groovy/asmescaping/SomeClass.groovy)

```
package asmescaping

class SomeClass {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def inputStream = SomeClass.getResourceAsStream('/info.txt')
        inputStream.eachLine { line ->
            String path = line.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')
            println "Path: $path"
        }
    }
}
```

That code appears to work:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/asmescaping.git
Cloning into 'asmescaping'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 0), reused 20 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (20/20), 58.33 KiB | 1.04 MiB/s, done.
~ $ 
~ $ cd asmescaping 
asmescaping (main)$ ./gradlew lib:run

> Task :lib:run
Path: C:/path/of/my/file
Path: C:/path2/of/my/file
Path: C:/path3/of/my/file
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff, This path will be coming from some other source and it will be 'C:\path\of\my\file' format . So is there a way we can do something here to handle such kind of situation? I was able to execute the same code above but my request was what if 'C:\path\of\my\file'

Comment: i tried to apply toString() to see if it converts the \ to \\. So i am looking for some possibilites around here.

Comment: "Jeff, This path will be coming from some other source and it will be 'C:\path\of\my\file' format . " - You may be confused about how character escaping works.  If you read the value in dynamically and the value is `'C:\path\of\my\file'`, the code above will work.  You just wont' have the hardcoded value in your source code.  The `replaceAll` would work exactly the same.

Comment: "i tried to apply toString() to see if it converts the \ to \\." - `toString` won't do any character substution.  `toString` will return whatever characters are in the `String`.